# Python - extract a text from string after the initial extraction of the number

Tags: python, pandas, text

My little school project gets a bit more complicated hence I am looking for a help. I have a data from with some text in Col1 that I use to extract the max numeric value. Now, I have been trying to use that extracted number to extract with any characters before and after it (from space for pre-fix and until space for suffix).

Here is my code:

```
from numpy import floor, int64
from numpy.core import numeric
import pandas as pd

data = [['aaa', 10], ['nick12 text 1 a 1000a', 15], ['juli078 aq 199 299-01 aaa', 14]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['col1', 'col2'])
print(df.dtypes)

pat = (r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
df['Number'] = df['col1'].str.extractall(pat).astype(int).max(level=0)
df['Number'] = df['Number'].fillna(0)
df['Number'] = df['Number'].astype(int)

print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
```

I want to add another column NumberText so my final result looks like this:

```
                        col1  col2  Number NumberText
0                        aaa    10       0  
1      nick12 text 1 a 1000a    15    1000  1000a
2  juli078 aq 199 299-01 aaa    14     299  299-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['NumberText'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word if str(x['Number']) in word else '' for word in x['col1'].split(' ')]).strip(), axis=1)
```

`Output:`

```
                        col1  col2  Number NumberText
0                        aaa    10       0           
1      nick12 text 1 a 1000a    15    1000      1000a
2  juli078 aq 199 299-01 aaa    14     299     299-01
```